# Delete lines that matches a string before comma

Tags: text-processing

I am quite new to bash scripting and so any help would be much appreciated. Below is what I want to achieve.

I have two text files. I want to delete all of the lines on the first file where it matches any of my string on the second file before the a comma.

e.g.

File 1:

```
this_is_a_test.txt,11dsdsdsdsd
this_is_a_test24.txt,545467ddd
this_is_a_test22,121244442
```

File 2:

```
this_is_a_test.txt
this_is_a_test24.txt
this_is_a_test22
```

Desired Output:
Blank

Comment: for your given sample, a simple `grep -Fvf file2 file1` will work, assuming the strings in file2 will only match first column data of file1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use:

```
grep -vFf file2 file1
```

Beware that it still delete lines although it matches after the comma.

Answer (score 0):

A simple `sed` trick can do this.

```bash
IFS='
' # If whitespaces exist in file 2
cat file2.txt | while read i; do
  sed -i '/^'"$i"',/d' file1.txt
done
```